# Infix to postfix algorithm

Tags: c++, postfix-notation

I've been working on a algorithm to convert "a+b*c-d/e" to it's postfix form. I've ready the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm wiki but am having problem with my logic. When I print out my Queue, I get "a b c d e" with no operators. It seems nothing is getting pushed into my Stack? Or if it is, it isn't getting pushed into my Queue. My Queue / Stack is being implemented by a double linked list class I created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
using namespace std;

int oper(char c)
{
    switch(c)    {
        case '!':
            return 4;
        case '*':  case '/': case '%':
            return 3;
        case '+': case '-':
            return 2;
        case '=':
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main () {

    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();


    string infix = "a+b*c-d/e";
    Stack *holder = new Stack();
    Queue *newstring = new Queue();
    int length = infix.length();
    char temp;
    char prev;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        temp = infix[i];
        if((temp == '+') || (temp == '-') || (temp == '*') || (temp == '/'))
        {
            if (holder->isEmpty())
            {
                holder->push(temp);
                prev = temp;
                continue;
            }
            if(oper(temp)<oper(prev))
            {
            newstring->queue(holder->popStack());
            temp = '\0';
            continue;
            }   
            else
            holder->push(temp);
            prev = temp;
        }
        else 
        newstring->queue(temp);

}
while(!holder->isEmpty())
{
    newstring->queue(holder->popStack());
}
newstring->printQueue();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get the debugger out, and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

your code part ::

```
        if(oper(temp)<oper(prev))
        {
        newstring->queue(holder->popStack());
        temp = '\0';
        continue;
        }
```

this part of the code dosent get a hit at all ......
the string provided in the input "a+b*c-d/e"

see this ::

```
 if(oper(temp)<oper(prev))
```

the condition is to check the priority of the previous operator with respect to the currently scanned one in the variable temp but there is no statement outside the previous if statement(condition where stack is empty) to extract or assign the prev variable from the options available in the stack hence the initial value of "+" is used for evaluation of the if condition which is less than "*" and "\" , and is at the same level with "-" but not greater as a result the second if condition never gets satisfied and dosent get a hit.

thats probably why when you pop nothing comes out of the stack , and thats how you get your current result. you would need to visit the code again and make appropriate changes.

hope this helps  , have a nice day ahead.